# Probability problem related to 2 rooks on a 8×8 chessboard

Tags: probability, chessboard

Two distinct squares are chosen uniformly at random on an $8\times 8$ chessboard, and rooks are placed on these squares. What is the probability that they will attack each other?

Edit : thanks everyone for their concern. I solved it :p. No matter where I place my rook it has 14 squares to go through in order to kill another one so my probability would be 14/63 or 2/9

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: What have you tried? If you place one rook then how many fields are under attack of it?

Comment: You should write up your solution as encouraged by the FAQ.  After some delay you will be able to accept it.  Writing it up is a good way to make sure you really understand the question.  What is nvm?  I think of it as nonvolatile memory, but that does not seem to apply here.

Comment: Hint: when you place a rook on a board, how many squares does it cover (not including its own)?

Comment: @RossMillikan I had the same question and had to google. It is supposed to mean never mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

total options for placing first rook are 64 and second is 63
now in our scenario first rook can be placed at any of $64$ but second must be place in the $14$ affected boxes.
answer is $\dfrac {14}{63}$.